# Проверка работоспособности приложения

Tags: windows

Есть ли какой-нибудь удобный и быстрый способ проверки работоспособности написанного приложения в разных версиях операционной системы *Windows*?

Существуют ли какие-нибудь другие способы помимо средств виртуализации (*VirtualBox*, к примеру )?

Comment: **Нет.** И даже виртуализация не дает 100% гарантии работоспособность на данной операционной системе, поскольку эта самая виртуализация добавляет несколько логических прослоек в операции, производимые ОС.

Comment: `Internet Explorer`, например, тестируют на целом парке физических машин с разными ОС и настройками.

Comment: За инфу спасибо, а вот только вывод из всего этого какой?

Comment: На первом этапе протестировать на разных версиях в VirtualBox. Далее, если позволяет машина, иметь на диске несколько версий виндов. Тестировать в них. Думаю, ниже Windows 2000 идти нет смысла. В конце можно попросить знакомых, у которых разные версии на компе стоят, погонять твое приложение. Если, конечно, они позволят.

Comment: Да мне бы вполне хватило Win XP/7/Vista. А так, видимо, придется просить друзей и знакомых...

Comment: Но более-менее адекватные решения данной проблемы я еще подожду...

Comment: @Asen, найми толпу тестеров, или просто раздай программу для тестирования как можно большему количеству людей.

Comment: Скорее всего так и сделаю - пройдусь с приложением по компьютерам знакомых.

Comment: Так-то тестить в виртуалке проще, если программа не большая. Запустил, проверил, усыпил, запустил другую версию... Можно даже наверное какой-нить скрипт на писать, который бы автоматом мышеклики делал. Эх, винды - как в них все сложно...

Answer (score 1):

Обратной совместимостью занимаются разработчики ОС, потому некоторые программы старых версий все же получается запустить в режиме совместимости.
Кстати, для тестирования сайтов существуют сервисы, которые дают оценку работы в разных браузерах.

Comment: ну а какие версии форточки тебя интересуют? мне даж сложно представить, что у тебя за приложения, что бы беспокоится о совместимости... для 3.11 и 95 точно не надо, для хр, милениум и 2000... это семейство нт, виста и семерка вроде бы тоже все "читают"

Comment: Криво слепленные на Дельфях трояны в плане обратной совместимости не очень хороши. Собственно, это и причина того, что никто не хочет тестировать их добровольно :-)

Comment: Кстати, о троянах и речи никакой быть не может! И кто вам только сказал, что никто не хочет тестировать приложение добровольно?

Comment: @Asen, да ладно, весна показала, кто где гадил уже :D

Comment: @Asen, ну я про недавнюю историю с акком @karmadro4 и наказанием виновного. Про то, каких людей немного жаль, которые из-за того что их так немного подтралливают, копят желчь и темными ночами планируют отмщение...

Comment: А чо ананимного-то? Ананимус штоле? Или за базар свой не отвечаешь? :D

Comment: @karmadro4, скажу честно, что мне вас немного жаль...ведь такие люди, как вы в реальной жизни представляют из себя неприятных троллей, живущих где попало и как попало. Вот и живите ради своих 500 очков рейтинга.

Comment: @Asen, а уж как [мне вас жаль](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81_%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C)... :-D
@neoascetic, похоже он всё еще думает, что мы - одно лицо О_о

Comment: Ну на такие страницы заходят лишь те, кто описан на той странице.

Интересно, и кто только его плюсует....

Comment: Я плюсую. А исчо читаю регулярно лурку. Особенно ндравицца [вот эта статья](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

Comment: "Школота", как её любят называть, определяется не возрастом, а отношением к тем или иным вещам.

Comment: @Asen, для начала перестаньте обижаться и оправдываться, подобно ребенку. И хватит поднимать эту всем надоевшую тему (не конкретный топик, а вообще).

Answer (score 0):

Наибольшие сложности могут возникнуть с приложениями, которые работают с реестром или файлами по системным путям. При включенном UAC могут быть довольно большие проблемы с работоспособностью.
Для таких тестов есть [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352) (описание возможностей [тут](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/cc507852.aspx)).
Ну чеклист [Designing UAC Applications for Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756973).

Также серьезные проблемы возникают при использовании сторонних библиотек, версии которых, на клиентских компьютерах могут отличаться, тут помогут системные требования и локальное тестирование на все новых версиях библиотек.

ЗЫ Без ОТК - жизнь программеров мрачна.

Comment: Вот, кстати, UAC - тоже одна из проблем. У кого-то на некоторые( или все ) локальные диски установлен запрет на запись, где-то реестр закрыт...

P.S   Из вышенаписанного может показаться, что я создаю тупую троянскую программу, в реальности все чуть ли не наоборот. Программа для локальной слежка за изменениями в файловой системе.